# classList and window.onscroll issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm learning html, css and js and I'm trying to make a sticky navbar, so that when I scroll down the page, the navbar sticks at the top.

At first, using this code worked:

html:

```
<div class="navBarContainer" id="navbar">
   <a class="navBar" href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a class="navBar" href="contacts.html">Contattaci</a>
   <a class="navBar">La storia</a>
   <a class="navBar" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
   <a class="navBar">Eventi</a>
   <select id="brancaDropdown" onchange = "onChange()">
       <option value="lupetti" id="option" selected>Lupetti</option>
       <option value="reparto" id="option">Reparto</option>
       <option value="clan" id="option">Clan</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

js:

```
let navBar = document.getElementById("navbar");
let navBarOffset = navBar.offsetTop;
window.onscroll = stickScrollbar();
function stickScrollbar() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= navBarOffset) {
        navBar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        navBar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

then, the next day, I figured out that it wasn't working anymore. Window.onscroll wasn't firing (I made the function call an alert), so I tried to bind the "onscroll" to the body, and it fires, but I still don't know why window.onscroll isn't fine. Anyways, I thought the problem was solved, but classList.add()/remove() wasn't working. Instead of scrolling, I tried to make the class change by the click of a button, same result. So I tried with onload, using the body element, but it didn't work as well. I'm using Chrome.
Please help, this is driving me mad.

Comment: This basically looks like a typo. You have window.onscroll = stickScrollbar() which means you are running stickScrollbar and assigning the result of that to window.onscroll whereas what you need to do is assign an actual function to it so use window.onscroll = stickScrollbar.

Comment: @AHaworth just tried, it doesn't even trigger the onscroll event

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet which shows the problem as I can't understand how having those brackets there can work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys thanks all, I solved it, it was just a previus variable wrong declaired that caused an exeption, but because I'm working with visual studio code I wasn't notified. I declaired: `const calendar = getElementById("calendar")` without writing "document.".

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
let navBar = document.getElementById("navbar");
let navBarOffset = navBar.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function stickScrollbar(){
    if (window.pageYOffset >= navBarOffset) {
        navBar.classList.add("sticky");
    } else {
        navBar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

```css
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.container{
  background-color:red;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="navBarContainer" id="navbar">
       <a class="navBar" href="index.html">Home</a>
       <a class="navBar" href="contacts.html">Contattaci</a>
       <a class="navBar">La storia</a>
       <a class="navBar" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
       <a class="navBar">Eventi</a>
       <select id="brancaDropdown" onchange = "onChange()">
           <option value="lupetti" id="option" selected>Lupetti</option>
           <option value="reparto" id="option">Reparto</option>
           <option value="clan" id="option">Clan</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Or you just need to remove "()" from this line: window.onscroll = stickScrollbar();

Answer (score 0):

**According to your Question**
*You need stick the navbar on top, No need to use javascript*

If you want to stick navbar on the top just fix this `css` :

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```